# sharepoint calendar solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, c#-4.0, calendar

I need some directions developing something in Sharepoint.
i know c# , asp.net but never worked on sharepoint before, what i would like to do is to have a visual component ( a calendar) in which i would like to place events i pull from a database, or without placing events in that calendar, i would like the user to click a day on the calendar and get details.

my question is does anyone know about a tutorial, step by step, to develop a solution in sharepoint 2007 ? i have visual studio 2010 installed in my machine, and we do have a sharepoint installed in a remote server.

please help.

Comment: What does:  "my question is does anyone know about a tutorial, step by step, to install use sharepoint" mean?  You want to install it on your server?  Im confued by your question.

Comment: i edited my text, hope it's clear now

Comment: Will all of the users of the calendar have the Outlook 2007/2010 client installed?

Comment: yes they all have 2007 or 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend you develop a calendar solution inside of SharePoint.

Instead, I would recommend you develop a web service that serves the calendar data to the Outlook clients from the data source.  Most users of Outlook have it open most of the day to do email and calendar, and so you can feed this event data to their outlook calendar, via a subscription and they can overlay and view the data directly.  You dont have to write any Outlook plug ins, just write a web service in C# and asp.net and you are good to go.

There is a protocol, called stssync - that was developed to do just this.  The following blog post is a great introduction, step-by-step, and has sample source code to help you get started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa168130(office.11).aspx

His design allows you to easily add your own data source type to get the event data into outlook.

The post is rather old, but trust me it works with the new clients (2007 and 2010). Most of the users appreciate that the data they want to see is inside the outlook client and they don't have to go to SharePoint to get the data.

Hope this helps.